The \bibliography not working and following the IEEEtrans bibliography style?
I am trying to use IEEEtran bibliography style. However, i am not able to generate as per the IEEEtran bibliography style. Precisely, the bibitems in the file (named Newbibliography.tex) are placed as:
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi**

\bibitem{cisco}
Cisco, “White Paper: Cisco Visual Networking Index: Global Mobile Data Traffic Forecast

\bibitem{cisco2}

\end{bibliography}

In the main file, the bibliography is invoked as:
\input{Newbibliography.tex}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

The references are generated as:


Cisco, White Paper: Cisco Visual Networking Index: Global Mobile Data Traffic Forecast
Update, 2018-2023, Tech. Rep., March. 20120.


However, i would like to generate the reference as:

[1] Cisco, White Paper: Cisco Visual Networking Index: Global Mobile Data Traffic Forecast.
Update, 2018-2023, Tech. Rep., March. 20120.

What is the solution to the above problem?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your write-up is quite confusing. You claim to be employing the IEEEtran bibliography style. However, the file Newbibliography.tex merely contains a thebibliography environment with two \bibitem statements. For sure, you're not giving us a reason to believe that BibTeX (which makes use of IEEEtran.bst) is actually involved. Please clarify your document setup.

By all means, do please replace \end{bibliography} with \end{thebibliography}.

I replaced \end{bibliography} with \end{thebibliography} but it still does not work.
I am not adding the bibliography as it is really used. The bibliography is written in the file Newbibliography.tex and the bibliography items are added as i have written in the initial description.

Of course it doesn’t work; the change I suggested in my second comment simply removes a bothersome syntax error. The real problem is that your test document does not to use BibTeX at all and hence cannot utilize the IEEEtran bibliography style. Merely adding a \bibliographstyle directive does not suffice.

In order to comply with the IEEE rules, you should use a .bib file and use BibTeX to generate the LaTeX version.
Here I use filecontents* in order to make the example self-contained.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{ciscowp,
  author={{Cisco}},
  title={White Paper: Cisco Visual Networking Index:
    Global Mobile Data Traffic Forecast Update, 2018--2023},
  note={{March}, 20120},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\cite{ciscowp}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

Running LaTeX, BibTeX and LaTeX again, you get

